# R: Apriori Algorithm does not find any association rules

Tags: r, data-science, prediction, apriori

I generated a dataset holding two distinct columns: an ID column associated to a customer and another column associated to his/her active products:

```
head(df_itemList)

      ID      PRD_LISTE
1     1       A,B,C
3     2       C,D
4     3       A,B
5     4       A,B,C,D,E
7     5       B,A,D
8     6       A,C,D
```

I only selected customers that own more than one product. In total I have 589.454 rows and there are 16 different products.

Next, I wrote the data.frame into an csv-file like this:

```
df_itemList$ID <- NULL
colnames(df_itemList) <- c("itemList")
write.csv(df_itemList, "Basket_List_13-08-2020.csv", row.names = TRUE)
```

Then, I converted the csv-file into a basket format in order to apply the apriori algorithm as implemented in the arules-package.

```
library(arules)  
txn <- read.transactions(file="Basket_List_13-08-2020.csv", 
                         rm.duplicates= TRUE, format="basket",sep=",",cols=1)
txn@itemInfo$labels <- gsub("\"","",txn@itemInfo$labels)
```

The summary-function yields the following output:

```
summary(txn)
transactions as itemMatrix in sparse format with
 589455 rows (elements/itemsets/transactions) and
 1737 columns (items) and a density of 0.0005757052 

most frequent items:
                   A,C                    A,B                     C,F                     C,D
                  57894                   32150                   31367                   29434 
                  A,B,C                 (Other) 
                  29035                  409575 

element (itemset/transaction) length distribution:
sizes
     1 
589455 

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      1       1       1       1       1       1 

includes extended item information - examples:
                                                                             labels
1 G,H,I,A,B,C,D,F,J
2 G,H,I,A,B,C,F
3 G,H,I,A,B,K,D

includes extended transaction information - examples:
  transactionID
1              
2             1
3             3
```

Now, I tried to run the apriori-algorithm:

```
basket_rules <- apriori(txn, parameter = list(sup = 1e-15, 
                                              conf = 1e-15, minlen = 2, target="rules"))
```

This is the output:

```
   Apriori

Parameter specification:
 confidence minval smax arem  aval originalSupport maxtime support minlen maxlen target  ext
       0.01    0.1    1 none FALSE            TRUE       5   1e-15      2     10  rules TRUE

Algorithmic control:
 filter tree heap memopt load sort verbose
    0.1 TRUE TRUE  FALSE TRUE    2    TRUE

Absolute minimum support count: 0 

set item appearances ...[0 item(s)] done [0.00s].
set transactions ...[1737 item(s), 589455 transaction(s)] done [0.20s].
sorting and recoding items ... [1737 item(s)] done [0.00s].
creating transaction tree ... done [0.16s].
checking subsets of size 1 done [0.00s].
writing ... [0 rule(s)] done [0.00s].
creating S4 object  ... done [0.04s].
```

Even with a ridiculously low support and confidence, no rules are generated...

```
summary(basket_rules)
set of 0 rules
```

Is this really because of my dataset? Or was there a mistake in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Your summary shows that the data is not read in correctly:

```
most frequent items:
                   A,C                    A,B                     C,F                     C,D
                  57894                   32150                   31367                   29434 
                  A,B,C                 (Other) 
                  29035                  409575
```

Looks like "A,C" is read as an item, but it should be two items "A" and "C". The separating character does not work. I assume that could be because of quotation marks in the file. Make sure that `Basket_List_13-08-2020.csv` looks correct. Also, you need to skip the first line (headers) using `skip = 1` when you read the transactions.

Answer (score 0):

@Michael I am quite positive now that there is something wrong with the .csv-file I am reading in. Since there are others who experienced similar problems my guess is that this is the common reason for error. Can you please describe how the .csv-file should look like when read in?

When typing in `data <- read.csv("file.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")` I get the following data.frame:

```
X     Prd
1     A
2     A,B
3     B,A
4     B
5     C
```

Is it correct that - if there are multiple products for a customer X - these products are all written in a single column? Or should be written in different columns?

Furthermore, when writing `txn <- read.transactions(file="Versicherungen2_ItemList_Short.csv",  rm.duplicates= TRUE, format="basket",sep=",",cols=1, skip=1)` and `summary(txn)` I see the following problem:

```
most frequent items:
A             B            C           A,B            B,A
1256          1235         456         235            125
```

(numbers are chosen randomly)

So the read.transaction function differentiates between A,B and B,A... So I am guessing there is something wrong with the .csv-file.

Comment: I think that was it. The .csv needs to contain different items in different columns.